# Cut & paste files in terminal like with a GUI file manager?

Tags: bash

I know of several file managers such as Midnight Commander that provide a GUI on console. However, if I need to Copy or Move a file, it requires me to type the path rather than navigating to the folder in GUI and choosing to paste, as in any typical GUI File Manager such as Nautilus.

I was wondering if there is a console based utility in Linux that would allow me to cut files, navigate to the desired target folder, and then paste them in the desired target folder? I am not looking for `mv` because I don't know beforehand where I want the files to land.

A custom script that temporarily stores the absolute paths of the files `readlink -f $0 >> ~.cache` until I call the command again `mv $(<~.cache) .; rm ~.cache` would probably do the trick. Does such a utility already exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Script

If you want to do it with your custom script, you'll need to make one variable to your target with full path, and move it to where you are, something like this:

```sh
$ _FROM="/home/mahdy/tmp"         # Full path of your target
$ cd path/to/dest                 # Where you want to move your directory
$ mv -v $_FROM .                  # Moving your directory
```

If you want to write a directory name, in where you're standing, you may define `$_FROM` like this too:

```sh
$ cd ~
$ _FROM=$(pwd)"/tmp"              # Output: /home/mahdy/tmp
```

You can define two function to work this in your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` or `.profile` or put it into a `script.sh` and source it manually, whatever you like, these are the functions:

```sh
# Target for moving
cut_target() {
    unset _FROM _TO
    [ $# -eq 0 ] && export _FROM=$(pwd) || export _FROM=$1
    [ "${_FROM:0:1}" != "/" ] && echo "W: Given query is not full path, changing \"$1\" to \"$(pwd)/$1\"" && export _FROM="$(pwd)/$1"
    [ ! -d "$_FROM" ] && echo "E: Given directory doesn't exist, please try again." && unset _FROM && exit 2
    echo "Moving \"$_FROM\"..."
}
# Move to path
cut_here() {
    [ $# -eq 0 ] && export _TO="." || export _TO=$1
    [ ! -d "$_TO" ] && echo "E: Given directory doesn't exist, please try again." && unset _TO && exit 2
    [ -z "$_TO" ] && mv -v $_FROM . || mv -v $_FROM $1
    unset _FROM _TO
}
```

Testing the functions:

```sh
$ cd ~/tmp                           # Directory which I want to move
$ cut_target                         # Setting current directory
# Result:
W: Given query is not full path, changing "tmp" to "/home/mahdy/tmp"
Target for moving: /home/mahdy/tmp
$ cd ~/new_folder                    # My destination             
$ cut_here                           # Moving to here
renamed '/home/mahdy/tmp' -> './tmp' # Result
```

You can also use full paths here:

```sh
$ cut_target /home/mahdy/tmp
$ cut_here /home/mahdy/new_folder
```

---

#### Using TUI File Managers

You also can do this with a Terminal-based file manager like `ranger` or `nnn`.

Installing `ranger`:

```sh
$ pacman -S ranger                 # ArchLinux
$ apt install ranger               # Debian "stretch"
$ dnf install ranger               # Fedora 32+
```

[Click here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Ranger) for full information about `ranger` and its configuration, I only make a short example here, read the wiki.

Copy your configuration to `~/.config/ranger` using in your own user:

```sh
$ ranger --copy-config=all
```

According to Arch wiki, you can see your keybindings for `ranger` typing: `?`->`k`, now you can learn the keybindings.

My keybinding for `cutting` is `F6` (default), which you can change this via modifing the files in `~/.config/ranger`, title of the folder will change to gray, and we can navigate to our destination and paste it to there using: `pp`

In action: select your folder, and cut it using `F6`, go to where you want to put it in, then paste it using `pp`:
[image: ranger file selection]
[image: ranger paste file]